# font.family : <フォント名>でエラーが起こる

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

初心者です。
jupyter notebookでmatplotlibを使ってグラフを作るときに文字化けしてしまうのを解決したくて、[こちらのサイト](http://pynote.hatenablog.com/entry/matplotlib-use-japanese-text)を参考に、macで作業しているのですが、

```
font.family : Hiragino Sans
```

と打っても

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

というエラーが起こってしまいます…

同サイトでも`font.family : <フォント名>`は引用符で囲ったりしないと書いてあるので、正直何がおかしいのかよくわかりません。

どうしたら解決できるのか分かる方いたらご教授いただきたいです。
よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: matplotlibrc を編集していますか？　Python ファイルや Notebook のセルを編集していませんか？

Comment: jupyter notebookを開いた状態でファイルを作ってしまっていました…
matplotlibrcを開いて、

pip install japanize-matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import japanize_matplotlib
と打ったところ、解決できました！！
ありがとうございました！

Comment: 解決して良かったです！　もし良ければ、是非[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けませんか？　投稿して暫くたてば、自分の投稿を承認することもできるようになります :)

Comment: stackoverflow初心者ですみません笑
やってみます！！

Answer (score 2):

jupyter notebookでは、はじめにホームディレクトリが開かれている状態ですが、
そこで新しいPythonファイルを作成していました…

（jupyter notebookの）ホームディレクトリから、./matplotlib/matplotlibrcを開き、そこで新しくPythonファイルを開きます。
そして、まず

```
pip install japanize-matplotlib
```

でパッケージをインストールします。
次に

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import japanize_matplotlib
```

と打ったところ、フォントファミリーが、IPAexGothicになってくれました！
試しに、

```
import matplotlib as mpl
print(mpl.rcParams['font.family'])
```

で確認してみたら、ちゃんと

```
['IPAexGothic']
```

と出てくれました！

（もしかしたら、matplotlibrcファイル内に、
ipaexg.ttf
ipaexm.ttf
という２フォルダーがあったからかもしれません
※このフォントファイルは[こちら](https://news.mynavi.jp/article/zeropython-3/)を参考にしました）

以上、jupyter notebookでフォントファミリーを変更することに成功しました！！
ありがとうございました！